# What does it isn't hindsight means?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does it isn't hindsight means? Can someone help me with this. Does it mean it isnt looking back in the past?

> **Bryce Spalding**
> Nobody likes Captain Hindsight, but the Angels legit might of set their franchise back 5-7 years by "going all-in" at the deadline.
>
> **Evan**
> didn't you think this beforehand? it isn't hindsight.
> <sub>[Source](https://twitter.com/bryce_spalding/status/1694578126003548261)</sub>

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full sentence and surrounding context where you found these words. Why do you think it doesn't simply mean that something is not hindsight?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: OK. It means exactly what it says. This situation isn't hindsight. That's it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does hindsight mean in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342991/what-does-hindsight-mean-in-this-sentence)

Comment: "might of" should be spelled **might've**, i.e. "might have".

Answer (score 3):

Wiktionary defines [hindsight](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hindsight) thusly:

> Realization or understanding of the significance and nature of events after they have occurred.

In other words, calling something *hindsight* implies that the significance was not known when the events occurred.

Bryce Spalding seems to be suggesting that in 2030, we will look back at trades made by the Angels at "the deadline" (which I believe would be 31 July 2023) and conclude that those trades were mistakes and set the team back 5-7 years. It seems implicit in his choice of words that this is not obvious now.

However Spalding wrote this on 24 August. Evan seems to be implying that Spalding had believed this already for 3-4 weeks prior to writing this post, in other words while the events were happening, and as such it is an incorrect use of the term *hindsight* to apply it to the opinion that Spalding believes we might have in 2030.

This was way more analysis than the exchange probably deserves.

Comment: so it isn't hindsight means the person understood the situation before it occurred?

Answer (score 0):

Zhuge Liang is an ancient Chinese figure. I asked my Chinese friend about it, and he said that Zhuge Liang was a famous military strategist in ancient times, and he could predict events like a god.
Hindsight is an ironic term, saying that you don't think about anything before doing it, but after it is over, you just point fingers and talk about everything. It's like you already knew all this, but you didn't know it, you only found out after it happened